# como colocar de forma simples um ícone na actionBar?

Tags: java, android, xml

Quero colocar um ícone na minha ActionBar já procurei por essa informação aqui no StackOverFlow, mas as respostas que encontrei são muito complicadas (sou iniciante) e por isso queria saber se tem uma forma bem simples.

Comment: Mostre, por favor, um exemplo de resposta que encontrou e o que achou complicado nela para que possamos julgar se dá pra simplificá-las.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a `Toolbar` para isso.

A `Toolbar` substitue a `ActionBar` padrão do Android e com ela é bem mais fácil de trabalhar.

Primeiramente, você deverá configurar o tema da sua aplicação para suportar a `Toolbar`, dizendo que você quer alterar a `ActionBar` padrão (não esqueça de alterar no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`):

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="Seu.Tema" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/suaPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/suaPrimaryDarkColor</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Seu.Tema">
        ...
</application>
```

Agora, você precisa colocar a `Toolbar` em seu layout. Lembre-se que ele é um componente qualquer do Android, então ele deve estar dentro do seu `.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Uma vez no `.xml`, agora você consegue manipuna-la em sua classe. Dentro dela, você precisa dizer a sua `Activity` que você quer trocar a `ActionBar` padrão, para isso você deve utilizar o método `setSupportActionBar()`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Pronto, agora sua `Toolbar` já é a sua `ActionBar` e você pode customiza-la como quiser. Para alterar o ícone padrão (ou o `Navigation Icon`), você simplesmente:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.seu_icone);
```

Comment: muito obrigado. foi de grande ajuda!